# Do not redirect URL for an add-on domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a main domain (`maindomain.com`) and an add-on domain (`addondomain.com`) hosted at the same server, both with blogs. The files for the add-on domain, which is running WordPress, are in a directory under the root of the main domain. The main domain used to have a WordPress blog, but now I use different software, so I want to redirect `http://maindomain.com/feed` to a FeedBurner URL. In the `.htaccess` in the root of the main domain, this rule

`Redirect /feed/ http://feeds.feedburner.com/MyFeed`

successfully redirects the feed for the main URL. The trouble is that it also redirects the feed for the add-on domain, so `http://addondomain.com/feed/` also points to that FeedBurner URL.

How can I create redirects just for the main domain and not for the add-on domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite. It may already be enabled by default, but if not, on Linux

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

And then at to your .htaccess the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com$
RewriteRule ^feed http://feeds.feedburner.com/feed [QSA,L,R=301]
```